# Magento keeps auto-checking "Use default value" box in category description field after save

Tags: category, admin, ce-1.4.0.1

I have a problem with Magento community edition 1.4.0.1. When I go to edit store categories, not the global one but for specific store for **some** categories (not all of them) Magento keeps auto-checking the "Use Default Value" box for selected fields like "Desctipion" or "Meta Description". This is a problem because the next time you go to that category to edit "Name" for example you have to manually uncheck those boxes to preserve data in them after next save.
To explain in more details please check the screenshot attached.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Seems like a bug.

Comment: Agreed with @Zyava. Verify by checking a stock version of 1.4, and see if it's been patched by looking through release notes (Magento's bug tracker for v1 is worthless) or testing newer versions.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, testing newer versions is not an option as this has to be fixed. I will compare it with stock and check release notes.

Answer (score 1):

Do you remove the content of the description field? We fixed a bug on the bugathon on the last weekend. There is a displaying bug, the check whether the field should be used from the default is `isset()` against an array which value is `NULL`.

https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/pull/217

And it should be this commit, my internet is buggy at the moment, so I can't check:

https://github.com/magento/bugathon_march_2013/commit/b9b344085c7d14bfdd1babb75677c931f2785209